# How do I create an alias to an existing linked server without recreating it?

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to create an alias for an existing linked Sql Server (2012). I am tasked to write some stored procedures against its tables, but I would like to avoid prefixing every single table with the linked server's name. It's unwieldy, makes it tiring to read, and painful to navigate around it.

Unfortunately, the only information I've managed to find requires recreating the linked server with an alias. I presume it requires reauthentication which requires waiting until the DBAs can get to it. I did encounter a SYNONYM feature, but it appears to only support low level SQL objects.

Is it even possible?

Comment: No - it is not possible. You should be explicitly naming every object referenced in any SQL Query with at least 2 parts. For remote objects, you must use 4 parts (or openquery). Those are the rules. Perhaps the real problem is a system design that relies on information split between two instances? No one can really help with that.

Comment: I here you, but it wasn't my design. The local DB belongs to one application with stored procedures to query data stored on the remote DB. Believe it or not, it's a huge improvement over relaying data through web services on the remote and local systems, requiring a web server in-between. The performance was abysmal to say the least.